Displaying AWS Rekognition prediction on a different html
I’m working on a web application that uses AWS Rekognition to predict gym equipment from uploaded images. The image upload and prediction work correctly, but I’m having trouble displaying the prediction on a separate HTML page.
homepage.html: Allows users to upload an image and sends it to an AWS Lambda function for prediction.
results.html: Should display the prediction result.
Even though the prediction result is logged correctly in the browser’s console, the results.html page shows "Equipment not found" instead of the actual prediction.
Code for homepage.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gym Equipment Exercise Finder</title>
    <style>
        /* Your existing CSS here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 style="font-family: Times New Roman, serif">Workout Wizard</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="homepage.html">Home</a>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-content">
            <h1>Find Your Workout!</h1>
            <p>Upload a photo of gym equipment and get exercises you can do with it.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="upload-section">
        <div class="upload-container">
            <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
            <label for="imageInput">
                <img src="camera.png" alt="Upload Icon">
                <p>Drop an image here</p>
                <p>or</p>
                <p>click to browse</p>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button onclick="uploadImage()">Submit</button>
    </section>
    <footer>
        &copy; 2024 Workout Wizard. All rights reserved.
    </footer>
    <script>
        function uploadImage() {
            const imageInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');
            if (!imageInput || !imageInput.files || imageInput.files.length === 0) {
                alert("Please choose an image file.");
                return;
            }

            const selectedFile = imageInput.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                const base64EncodedImage = event.target.result.split(',')[1];
                fetch('https://t6mn1ryxc4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Gym_Equipments/predict', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ image: base64EncodedImage }),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Lambda Response:', data);
                    localStorage.setItem('predictedEquipment', data);
                    console.log('Stored in localStorage:', localStorage.getItem('predictedEquipment'));
                    window.location.href = "results.html";
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    alert('Error uploading image.');
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Code for results.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Results</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f3f4f6;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #6200a9; 
            padding: 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            color: white;
        }
        header img {
            height: 50px;
        }
        nav {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        nav a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 0 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        nav a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .result-section {
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        footer {
            background-color: #6200a9;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        footer a {
            color: #ff7f50;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        footer a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Workout Wizard</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="homepage.html">Home</a>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="result-section">
        <h1>Prediction Result</h1>
        <p id="result">Loading...</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        &copy; 2024 Workout Wizard. All rights reserved. | <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="termsandconditions.html">Terms of Service</a>
    </footer>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            // Retrieve the prediction result from localStorage
            const prediction = localStorage.getItem('predictedEquipment');
            if (prediction) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = prediction;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'No equipment predicted';
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

lambda function:
import json
import boto3
 
bucket_name = "gymhtml"
 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime
 
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 
def saveToS3(image_binary):
    # Get the current timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
    # Generate a filename with the timestamp
    filename = f'uploads/{timestamp}.jpg'
    print("filename: ", filename)
    try:
        # need to save the image as image/jpeg content type
        s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename, Body=image_binary, ContentType='image/jpeg')
        # Log success message
        print(f"Image saved to S3: s3://{bucket_name}/{filename}")
        return filename
    except ClientError as e:
        # Log the error
        print("Error:", str(e))
        return None
 
def predictImage(photo):
    rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
    model = "arn:aws:rekognition:us-east-1:414942631188:project/gymequipment/version/gymequipment.2024-07-31T18.03.52/1722420232922"
    min_confidence = 60
 
    #Call DetectCustomLabels
    response = rekognition.detect_custom_labels(Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Name': photo}},
        MinConfidence=min_confidence,
        ProjectVersionArn=model)
    print(response['CustomLabels'])
    result = json.dumps(response['CustomLabels'][0])
    #print to the log for debugging purposes
    print(response['CustomLabels'][0]["Name"])
    return response['CustomLabels'][0]["Name"]
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    msg = "INVALID REQUEST"
    print( event );
    #if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
        # Extract the base64-encoded image and filename from the request body
        #request_body = json.loads(event['body'])
    request_body = json.loads(event['body'])
    image_base64 = request_body['image'];
    # Decode the base64-encoded image
    image_binary = base64.b64decode(image_base64)
    #save image to S3
    imagefilename = saveToS3(image_binary)
    #msg = 'Hello from Lambda!'
    #msg = predictImage(imagefilename)
    msg = predictImage(imagefilename)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(msg)
    }


You have shown us a lot of code. Can you simplify things down to something that other people can attempt and reproduce themselves? Also, you mention that it displays "Equipment not found", but there doesn't seem to be any code that generates this message. For tips on asking a good question, please see: How do I ask a good question?

apologies, I meant 'No equipment predicted' under results.html.

You have a line that says if (prediction) { -- what does the prediction variable contain when it runs that line?
